# Here Maps JS files is not loading

Tags: javascript, here-api

I have been working one Here Maps JS , I have proper Generated KEY also.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-clustering.js"></script>
```

Getting the following Response.
[image]

Can anyone let me know why its been like this?

Comment: I don't think you did anything wrong. It's looks like a [redirect 307](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) from Here Maps side. But in your question we're missing the code that is using those JS libraries. Something like [this](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js) `var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,{
  center: {lat:50, lng:5},
  zoom: 4,
  pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
});`

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me. All working fine, then suddenly the browser won't load the JS files. I can load them fine from the command line.[image: screen grab of console Loading failed messages]

Any ideas? Just wait and see if it goes away?